# Diferença entre else if e elsif

Tags: if, sintaxe, independente-de-linguagem

Sei que esses dois termos não existem na mesma linguagem (corrija-me se estiver errado), mas em algumas linguagens (C#, no exemplo abaixo), temos o seguinte código:

```
if(condicao){

...

} else if (condicao) {

 ...

}
```

Já em outras (Perl, no exemplo abaixo), temos:

```
if (condicao) {
    ...
}
elsif (condicao) {
    ...
}
```

Os dois provavelmente fazem a mesma coisa, mas existe alguma diferença na lógica dos dois? Ou na maneira como eles são interpretados/compilados pelo computador? Ou é apenas relacionado à sintaxe da própria linguagem?

Comment: É apenas açúcar sintático.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else if`, `elseif`, `elsif`, `elif`, e outras formas são apenas maneiras diferentes de escrever a mesma coisa, provavelmente cada uma está de acordo com a filosofia da sintaxe. Não há diferença alguma na execução delas, mas nada impede de alguma linguagem fazer algo diferente, só não faz sentido, seria só para confundir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).